# How to Hide Required Parameters Laravel Route

Tags: laravel, routes

So I have a booking system. Basically it has this route

```
localhost:8080/itpr/booking/details/{$bookingId}
```

Where `$bookingId` = is the `id` in the `booking_table`.

My question, is there a way to hide the `$bookingId` from my routes from the the user? I don't want other users to be able to access to other booking transaction just by changing the `$bookingId` in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is by submiting your post request via AJAX. But if you are not comfortable using ajax request. You can create a policy that allows only the owner of those booking to make change: see code below.

```
php artisan make:policy BookingPolicy --model=Booking
```

Register the policy in your AuthServiceProvider: `use App\Policies\BookingPolicy;`

```
protected $policies = [
    Booking::class => BookingPolicy::class,
];
```

Now inside your BookingPolicy then define policy for any method that you want to restrict users from. For example let make sure onl the authenticated user(owner) can update his booking. In this scenario we are assuming that you have user_id column in your Booking table and you have relationship between these 2 tables

```
public function update(?User $user, Booking $booking)
{
    return $user->id === $booking->user_id;
}
```

Now in your BookingController you can call implement the authorizing actions(can or cant)

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    if ($user->can('update', $booking)) {
       // Executes the "create" method on the relevant policy...
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will help :)

Comment: Yeah! This could probably work! But I'm thinking of adding the functions you suggested as a Middleware. That way I could also redirect users who are not supposed to fiddle around with other ID's

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using `$table->uuid('id');` for PK? So that the users are not going to guess other bookings easily.

Answer (score 0):

Add a check in your route if the booking `ID` is one that belongs to the user trying to access the `ID`. If not, redirect.

Otherwise, provide a dashboard like route showing the user bookings. then make an asynchronous call on the click using your `userID/bookingID` send that data to a template with a route that is something like your `booking/details`

Comment: Yeah! I'm planning to do it. Probably as a middelware to check if this ID belongs to that specific userId

Answer (score 0):

Please Check [Laravel Policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#policy-methods)  and define rules to check if the booking id is associated with the current user or not and . which can help you to secure the booking detail from unauthorized user.